# Jenkins server returns 500 error

Tags: 500-error, 500, jenkins

Having just installed jenkins on a debian 64bits lenny distro I started the 
server but when I connect to it I get the error:

```
Status Code: 500
Exception: The error below occurred during context initialisation, so no further requests can be processed:

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.90)
   at hudson.WebAppMain.installLogger(WebAppMain.java:252)
   at hudson.WebAppMain.contextInitialized(WebAppMain.java:106)
   at winstone.WebAppConfiguration.(WebAppConfiguration.java:889)
   at winstone.HostConfiguration.initWebApp(HostConfiguration.java:131)
   at winstone.HostConfiguration.(HostConfiguration.java:73)
   at winstone.HostGroup.initHost(HostGroup.java:85)
   at winstone.HostGroup.(HostGroup.java:45)
   at winstone.Launcher.(Launcher.java:196)
   at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:391)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(libgcj.so.90)
   at Main._main(Main.java:212)
   at Main.main(Main.java:61)
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream$InitializationException: Could not instantiate converter : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.extended.DurationConverter : null
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.dynamicallyRegisterConverter(XStream.java:735)
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.setupConverters(XStream.java:699)
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.(XStream.java:445)
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.(XStream.java:385)
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.(XStream.java:323)
   at hudson.util.XStream2.(XStream2.java:62)
   at hudson.model.Hudson.(Hudson.java:3656)
   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.90)
   ...12 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(libgcj.so.90)
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.dynamicallyRegisterConverter(XStream.java:728)
   ...19 more
Caused by: javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConfigurationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gnu.xml.datatype.JAXPDatatypeFactory
   at javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory.newInstance(libgcj.so.90)
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.extended.DurationConverter.(DurationConverter.java:33)
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(libgcj.so.90)
   ...20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gnu.xml.datatype.JAXPDatatypeFactory
   at java.lang.Class.forName(libgcj.so.90)
   at javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory.newInstance(libgcj.so.90)
   ...22 more


Stacktrace:

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.90)
   at hudson.WebAppMain.installLogger(WebAppMain.java:252)
   at hudson.WebAppMain.contextInitialized(WebAppMain.java:106)
   at winstone.WebAppConfiguration.(WebAppConfiguration.java:889)
   at winstone.HostConfiguration.initWebApp(HostConfiguration.java:131)
   at winstone.HostConfiguration.(HostConfiguration.java:73)
   at winstone.HostGroup.initHost(HostGroup.java:85)
   at winstone.HostGroup.(HostGroup.java:45)
   at winstone.Launcher.(Launcher.java:196)
   at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:391)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(libgcj.so.90)
   at Main._main(Main.java:212)
   at Main.main(Main.java:61)
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream$InitializationException: Could not instantiate converter : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.extended.DurationConverter : null
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.dynamicallyRegisterConverter(XStream.java:735)
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.setupConverters(XStream.java:699)
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.(XStream.java:445)
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.(XStream.java:385)
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.(XStream.java:323)
   at hudson.util.XStream2.(XStream2.java:62)
   at hudson.model.Hudson.(Hudson.java:3656)
   at java.lang.Class.initializeClass(libgcj.so.90)
   ...12 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(libgcj.so.90)
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.dynamicallyRegisterConverter(XStream.java:728)
   ...19 more
Caused by: javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConfigurationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gnu.xml.datatype.JAXPDatatypeFactory
   at javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory.newInstance(libgcj.so.90)
   at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.extended.DurationConverter.(DurationConverter.java:33)
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(libgcj.so.90)
   ...20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gnu.xml.datatype.JAXPDatatypeFactory
   at java.lang.Class.forName(libgcj.so.90)
   at javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory.newInstance(libgcj.so.90)
   ...22 more


Generated by Winstone Servlet Engine v0.9.10 at Wed Mar 23 14:32:32 GMT+01:00 2011
```

Any sugestions on how I can resolve this ?

Best regards,
FR

Comment: How have you installed it? Over the debian repos? Or have you downloaded the .war file and put it to Tomcat?

Comment: I installed it using the  jenkins source.
deb http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian binary/

Comment: Do you have any plugins installed and removed? I've found that installing lots of plugins to test tends to leave the "cruft" around in configuration files in $JENKINS_HOME, and even if the plugin is deleted/disabled it'll still try to parse those configuration elements - rarely, but occasionally with disastrous results.

Comment: aptitude install openjdk-6-jdk  installed this and got a diferent error... 

Status Code: 500
Exception:
Stacktrace:

org.apache.commons.jelly.JellyTagException: jar:file:/var/run/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/jenkins-core-1.403.jar!/lib/layout/layout.jelly:92:54:  java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
 at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.handleException(TagScript.java:709)
 at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:282)
 at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)

Answer (score 1):

I confirm that

aptitude install openjdk-6-jdk

solved my problem and my remaining issue is with the apache proxy to jenkins.

using lynx localhost:8080 I saw that jenkins was now working

Thanks for your help